# Can you identify this possibly Austro-Hungarian military uniform from either WW1 or before?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform, austria-hungary

My Great Grandfather died in 1929 at age 50, putting his possible year of birth at 1879. He was born and died in Istria, now modern-day Croatia. During his lifetime, however, this part of the world was under Austro-Hungarian (AH) rule, as the Austrian Littoral. AH's [K.U.K Kriegsmarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_Navy) was based there, and I wondered if his uniform had anything to do with that.

Can you help me identify my Great Grandfather's uniform pictured below?

[image: Petar Bako][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T0DI.jpg)

Comment: The hat looks vaguely like the three Jägers' hats seen on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_Army#/media/File:KuK_Infanterie_1898.jpg .

Comment: The hat appears to have a double eagle on it.  Which is the symbol of empire.  Both Russia and Austria Hungary were using the double eagle symbol in the late 1800- WWI.   Germany was using a single headed eagle at that time.   I found a picture of an Imperial Austrian  Shako cap with a double eagle on it, but it wasn't an exact match the wings were off.       https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymYvy.jpg

Comment: @kimchilover: Yes - I took one look at the hat and thought: Jäger or Tyrolean for sure.

Comment: The lanyard looks like those illustrated in http://www.austro-hungarian-army.co.uk/badges/lanyard1.htm , except the three pom-poms seem to be hidden.  According to this web site, the KuK Navy did not wear these lanyards.

Comment: Why don't you pass this question on to the mil history museum in Vienna:  https://www.hgm.at/en.html , described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_of_Military_History,_Vienna ?

Comment: Potrebbe essere un agente della Polizia austriaca

Comment: We are an English-language web site. Please post in English.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this uniform is from the **[k. k. Gendarmerie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K.k._Gendarmerie)** Here is a picture of their uniform from the same wiki page: [image] There are slight differences (eg number of buttons), but the design of both the hat and the coat is clearly very similar, and the man on the wiki link is a Gendarme officer (Hauptmann) from Bosnia-Herzegovina, while your Great-Grandfather was from another area of Austria-Hungary and probably of lower rank.

Here is another image of an Austrian gendarme-coat,  demonstrating the same epaulet on the left shoulder, and the cord hanging from it. [image] (This is a colonel (Oberst), so it has more cords)

It turns out that other K.u.K military units wore a similar design of coat (Waffenrock in fact) for example the [K.k. Landesschützen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K.k._Landessch%C3%BCtzen), so it is hard to be certain. It seems that gendarme after 1900 (other than Hungarian ones) were supposed to have helmets, not Jager-hats, but for example the Landesschützen (who wore Jager-hats) had a much lighter bluish hue on the Wafferock, that is very bright on black-and-white photos. But the one sided cord and epaulet I have only seen on gendarme uniforms.

The [K. k. Gendarmerie](https://www.facebook.com/pg/K.K.Gendarmerie/photos/?ref=page_internal) also has a Facebook page, they have a ton of photos of different uniforms, and perhaps can help with further research.